# Struggling with cipher

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm writing a common lisp program to encrypt and decrypt lists.  My problem is when I input:

```
(encode '((Computer)(Science)) 5)
```

It'll only output the first letter from each list, such as `"H K"`. Here's my code:

```
(defun alphabet ()
  (concatenate 'string
    "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))

(defun index-of (ch)
(position ch (alphabet)))

(defun char-at (position)
(subseq (alphabet) position (+ 1 position))) 

(defun encode-char (ch key)   
(char-at (+ (index-of (char(string ch)0)) key)))

 (defun encode-word (s key)
  (if s
    (concatenate 'string
      (encode-char (car s) key)
      (encode-word (cdr s) key))))  

(defun encode (list key)
  (if list
  (concatenate 'string
    (encode-word (car list) key)
    " "
    (encode (cdr list) key)))) 

(defun rindex-of (ch)
  (- (length (alphabet))
     (position ch (reverse (alphabet)))))

(defun decode-char (ch key)
  (char-at (- (rindex-of (char(string ch)0)) key)))

(defun decode-word (s key)
  (if s
    (concatenate 'string
      (decode-char (car s) key)
      (decode-word (cdr s) key))))  

(defun decode (list key)
  (if list
  (concatenate 'string
    (decode-word (car list) key)
    " "
    (decode (cdr list) key))))
```

Comment: please fix indentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make sure that the basic encoding/decoding is done on strings. Everything else makes little sense. Mixing in the input structure is to be avoided. Also avoid computing the alphabet over and over...

The alphabet is a string in a variable:

```
(defvar *alphabet*
  (format nil
    "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz~
     0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
```

The encoding functions:

```
(defun index-of (char alphabet)
  (position char alphabet))

(defun encode-char (char key alphabet)   
  (char alphabet
        (+ (index-of char alphabet) key)))

(defun encode-word (s key alphabet)
  (map 'string
       (lambda (char)
         (encode-char char key alphabet))
       s))
```

A helper function to join a bunch of things divided by div:

```
(defun join-to-string (list div)
  "Creates a new string of the elements of list with the div spliced in between."
  (with-output-to-string (s)
    (princ (first list) s)
    (loop for e in (rest list)
          do (princ div s) (princ e s))))

; CL-USER 6 > (join '(foo bar baz) '-)
; "FOO-BAR-BAZ"
```

Encoding your input:

```
(defun encode (list-of-lists key alphabet)
  (join-to-string (mapcar (lambda (word)
                            (encode-word (string word) key alphabet))
                          (mapcan #'copy-list list-of-lists))
                  " "))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 8 > (encode '((Computer Science) (Common Lisp)) 5 *alphabet*)
"HTRUZYJW XHNJSHJ HTRRTS QNXU"
```

**Style**

Note that you want to indent your code. Do it!

`rindex-of` is wasting valuable cycles. One would use `position` with a `:from-end t` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
(defun encode-char (ch key)   
  (char-at (+ (index-of (char(string ch)0)) key)))

(defun encode-word (s key)
  (if s
      (concatenate 'string
                   (encode-char (car s) key)
                   (encode-word (cdr s) key))))
```

A *word* in your problem is a list with symbols, e.g. `(Computer)`.
With this inputs, `encode-word` calls `encode-char` on the `car` of this list, namely `Computer` (the `cdr` is null and the recursion for the rest of the list returns NIL).
However, `encode-char` only look at the first character of `ch`, because it calls `(char (string ch) 0)`.
I presume you need `encode-symbol`, which will call `encode-char` for each character of the symbol's name.

However, your code is quite complex. Some remarks:

- Don't recompute the alphabet each time you need it. For example, define a closure:

  ```
  (let alphabet (concatenate ...)
    (defun alphabet ()
      alphabet))
  ```
- Indent your code properly: http://people.ace.ed.ac.uk/staff/medward2/class/moz/cm/doc/contrib/lispstyle.html
- Use meaningful names; sometimes short names are clear in context, but two letters abbreviations like `ch` are not idiomatic. It is either `c`, `char` or `character`. Also, `char-at` is lying because you compute a string.

> I'm a bit confused on how to go about making the encode-symbol function

Encoding a symbol is just getting the name of that symbol and encoding that; you could use either `symbol-name` or `string`:

```
(defun encode-symbol (symbol key) 
  (encode-string (string symbol) key))
```

Now, you can implement `encode-string`:

```
(defun encode-string (string key)
  (map 'string (lambda (c) (encode-char c key)) string))
```

- `'string` is the return type of [`MAP`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_map.htm).
- `(lambda ...)` is an anonymous function which is called for each character in the `string` sequence. I am using this to pass the `key` argument down to `encode-char`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on how to go about making the encode-symbol function, if you don't mind giving a tip.  What I've been trying is something like: (encode-char (char(string(car s))0) key), but I'm not sure how you would take the cdr of a the list.

Comment: Now I'm getting output: STORE: "H" does not fit into "", bad type
any suggestions?